# Using multiple background image in css3

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to use multiple background on a div without any success can any one suggest me where i am getting it wrong , below is the css i am using :

```
.box-text{
font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 22px;  
background-image:url('/images/p-top.png'), url('/images/p-center.png'),url('/images/p-bottom.png'); 
background-position: top center, center center, bottom center; 
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y,no-repeat;}

<div class="box-text">
variable text.............
</div>
```

Result i am getting :

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

I have done slice of the box to get 3 images one is the top one the other middle one for which i have use repeat-y and the third image is the bottom image to cover the box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background position is specified with the horizontal value first, so you should switch them:

```
background-position: center top, center center, center bottom;
```

Comment: yep thats correct, but how can i set the padding in it any ideas , coz if i set padding the images get disturbed i just want to set padding to text inside the image

Comment: not able to get the bottom image , the top and center image is working as expected

Comment: perfect , thanks , can you tell me the reason for alignment ,one more thing is there any way i can get this working in ie8

Comment: @MrA: The image are stacked on top of each other, so you need the top and bottom image to be over the middle image. IE8 doesn't support multiple background images, so you would use three elements instead to support older browsers.